# How do I substitute in vim editor?

Tags: vim, coding-style, editor, substitution

I want to substitute with vim editor a word but only on a portion of a code, that is to say the word "[iteration]" by "[index]". I know how to select the text to replace (visual mode) but I don't know how to apply a substitution on the text selected. The only thing I know to do is global substitution by typing `"%s/\[interation\]/\[index\]/g`: how can do the same on only selected text?

Answer (score 1):

After you select a block in visual mode, press `:`, and you'll get a prompt with `'<,'>`, representing the block you've selected. You can then add instructions to be performed on that block like `s/[interation]/[index]/g` (without the `%`!). I.e., you'll have `'<,'>s/[interation]/[index]/g`. Press <kbd>Enter</kbd> and you're good to go.

Comment: If you want a strict selection substitution, not just over-selected lines you should use `:'<,'>s/\%Vpattern\%V/new_pattern/g`.